Annihilating ideal of quotient rings of polynomial rings.
Let $f_1,\dots,f_r$ be homogeneous polynomials of degree 2 in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $r\leq n$.
If $f_r$ is a zero-divisor on $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]/(f_1,\dots, f_{r-1})$, I want to prove that there exists a polynomial $g\notin (f_1,\dots, f_r)$ such that $gf_r\in (f_1,\dots, f_{r-1})$.
This is equivalent to say ${\rm ann}(f_r)\nsubseteq (f_1,\dots, f_r)/(f_1,\dots, f_{r-1}).$
I want to prove this (maybe it is not true), but I have no some good ideals.

Your statement is wrong. You only have $g \not\in (f_1,f_2 ,\ldots,f_{ r-1})$.

Sorry,I didn't write it clearly before. I edit it agin.

What is your definition of zero divisor?

It seems to me that the statement is false. Take $n=1$ and let $f_1 = x^2,f_2 = x^2+x$, then $f_2 \cdot h \in (f_1) \iff h \in (x) = (f_1,f_2)$

@RHspqr Yes, you are right! if it needs $n\geq r$, your example will not hold.

@Mohan Here, $f_r$ is a zerodivisor implies there exists a nonzero element $g\in (f_1,\cdots,f_{r-1})$ such that $gf_r\in (f_1,\cdots,f_{r-1})$. My question is  whether there is a such $g\notin (f_1,\cdots,f_r)$ or not.

@Well Yeah, but the same would hold if we consider $(x^2),(x^2+x)$ in the ring $k[x,y]$

@RHspqr Here needs deg$f_i=2$.

@Well I don't know if I understand your reply well, but do you mean that $f_i$ needs to be homogeneous of degree $2$? It seems to me that $x^2,x^2+x \in k[x,y]$ are 2 polynomials of degree 2 which gives a counterexample.

@RHspqr Yes, $f_i$ needs homogeneous. Sorry..
